# Equivalence Partitioning for Name field

Tags: testcase, techniques

Equivalence Partitioning for Name field:

Requirement says the `Name` field shall:

- Accept alpha numeric characters and special characters `!@#$%&*
- Minimum 4 characters
- Maximum 40 characters
- First character must be a letter.

Now my questions are:

- How many equivalence partitions can be there in such a case?
- How to consider various permutations and combinations in such a case?

Example:

- 3 basic partitions
- Partition 1: <4 character (invalid condition)
- Partition 2: >40 characters (invalid condition)
- Partition 3: between 4&40 (Valid condition)

Now under each of these partitions, again we have various combinations:

- Partition 4: only alphabets (Again two more such as lower case and upper case)
- Partition 5: Only numbers (invalid condition)
- Partition 6: Only special characters (Invalid Condition)
- Partition 7: Alphabets and numeric
- Partition 8: Alphabets and special characters
  and so on...

There there will be so many combinations and on what basis shall we decide?

Secondly: Assume that we have several fields in a form (Such as user registration). Again in such case there will be several permutations and combinations.

What would be the best technique for deciding test cases?

Answer (score 1):

I would consider 3 parameters to decide on partitioning:

- Position
- Size
- and Input

---

With respect to **Position**, I would create 2 partitions:

> 1. **Alphabetic character at 1st position**, with rest as a valid condition (i.e size between 4 to 40, valid set of input).
> 2. **Non-Alphabetic character at 1st position**, with rest as a valid condition (i.e size between 4 to 40, valid set of input).

With respect to **Size**, I would create 3 partitions:

> 1. **Size < 4**, with rest as a valid condition (Alphabetic character at 1st position, rest as a valid set of input).
> 2. **Size >=4<=40**, with rest as a valid condition (Alphabetic character at 1st position, rest as a valid set of input).
> 3. **Size >40**, with rest as a valid condition (Alphabetic character at 1st position, rest as a valid set of input).

With respect to **Input**, I would create 2 partitions:

> 1. **Valid input** with rest as a valid condition (Alphabetic character at 1st position, size >=4<=40)
> 2. **Invalid input** (one of the character is illegal in input) with rest as a valid condition (Alphabetic character at 1st position, size >=4<=40)

Answer (score 0):

The three basic partitions look good if you use an alphabetic character in the first position and valid characters everywhere else.

Next partition would be a valid length with valid characters but starting with a non-alphabetic character.

Last partition would be a valid length with an alphabetic character in the first position and at least one illegal character after that (not alphanumeric and not any of !@#$%&*).

Unless I'm totally confused that should be all.

Answer (score 0):

First, you don't need to test conditions defined by partitions 4-8 on groups defined by partitions 1 and 2. These groups of input strings **fail a requirement**, and are therefore invalid. *"Fail fast, fail often!"*

Next, you have another "sink-or-swin" requirement that can cut your testing in half. Literally. Either the first character is a valid alphabetical character ("a"-"z" or "A"-"Z", inclusive) or not. Again, *"Fail fast, fail often!"*

Now you've got groups of input strings 4-40 chars long (inclusive), with a valid first char, is the time to test your partitioning scheme, which is a good one. You might, should actually, also include: *input string made up of alphanumeric chars and **invalid** special chars, e.g. "-". ";"* and so on.

As far as permutations goes, since you can't test ***all*** possible permutations, you should ***always*** test edge-cases and a random sampling of the "regular" cases. In your case I'd go with:

- Leave the input field empty and try to validate (this is a special case of invalid input, where the input is translated as *Null*, not just invalid) (invalid, of course!)
- 1/2/3 chars, randomly drawn from a pool of **both** *valid* and *invalid* chars (invalid!) (Why the insistence on *both* valid and invalid pools?)
- 4 chars, all alphabetical chars
- 4 chars, all numerical (invalid! *Why?*)
- 4 chars, all **valid** special chars (invalid! *Why?*)
- 4 chars, randomly drawn from pool of *valid* chars (you tell me, what's the expected result here? Think before you answer!)
- 4 chars, at least one, *randomly positioned* in the string, is an *invalid* special char (invalid, of course)
- 40 chars, randomly drawn from pool of *valid* chars (Again, tricky)
- 5-39 (inclusive) chars, randomly decided, chars randomly drawn from a pool of *valid* chars (Last of the tricky ones)

Lastly, if you can automate -- automate! Above I've listed 9 test cases categories. If you only run one test case from each "category" I can **assure** you you'll not have found bugs in the form validation mechanism. You need to run at least 5-6 test cases *from each "category"* to be *fairly* convinced that it's *almost* certainly bug-free. If you can't automate... buddy, I hate being in your shoes, you've got your work cut out for you. :)

Answer (score 0):

I would test:

**Negative tests**

LT 4 chars

GT 40 chars

GT 3 chars with non-alpha in pos 1

Non allowable special character in pos 2 - 40 (1 test, not all positions)

**Positive Tests**

GT 3 chars with lower case alpha in pos 1

GT 3 chars with upper case alpha in pos 1

Mark Smith.